# What does the MD in Oracle's MDSYS stand for?

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

Oracle has an user called MDSYS.

What does the MD stand for? Something like 'main database'?

Comment: See the [spatial concepts documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_intro.htm#SPATL440). "A schema (MDSYS) that prescribes the storage, syntax, and semantics of supported geometric data types"

Comment: Multi Dimensional System apparently https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Spatial_and_Graph

Comment: To support that, way back in the [8.0.4](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a53717/ch1.htm) and [8.0.5 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a53717/ch1.htm) it describes the Spatial Data option as "an option to include multi-dimensional (spatial) data in databases". It isn't a phrase they seem to use often though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi Dimensional System: [en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Spatial_and_Graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Spatial_and_Graph).

An option to include multi-dimensional (spatial) data in databases. It isn't a phrase they seem to use often though.